# Jquery prepend is not working in Chrome

Tags: jquery

my code on the windows load:

```
$(".directoryMedia ul li").prepend("<a href='#' class='RemoveProjectImage' title='Remove from Project'></a>");
```

works great on firefox

Comment: Use back slashes on your quotes (`'` into `\'`) inside your `.prepend()` so your final code is `$('.directoryMedia ul li').prepend('<a href=\'#\' class=\'RemoveProjectImage\' title=\'Remove from Project\'></a>');` or use different quotes (`"` and `'`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your string concatenation is not correct, also there is not text display in the link

```
$('.directoryMedia ul li').prepend("<a href='#' class='RemoveProjectImage' title='Remove from Project'>test content</a>");
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/BpAqy/1/)

Comment: actually the real one is this one: $(".directoryMedia ul li").prepend("<a href='#' class='RemoveProjectImage' title='Remove from Project'></a>");

Comment: @alexisdwd what do you want as the output

Comment: Sorry i didnt know how to paste a code im new im really sorry now you have the real code

Comment: the out would be just the link

Comment: the problem is realted to something elese no the code i did i guess